# Why SQL Server Management Studio 2014 can not connect?

Tags: sql-server

[image]  I have installed sql server 2014 in my windows 7.when i am trying to connect to 
  server it is always shown error either windows authentication or sql server 
  authentication.

**Error**:

```
Connect to Server
```

**Additional Information:**

```
  A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a     
  connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. 
  Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to 
  allow remote connections.
```

I checked `Services.msc` ---> Here server is running (MSSQL Server)

I started manually so,still it is showing cannot connect to server.

What's the issue? Can anyone help to solve this isssue?

Thanks.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060667/why-am-i-getting-cannot-connect-to-server-a-network-related-or-instance-speci and http://www.sqlmusings.com/2009/03/11/resolving-a-network-related-or-instance-specific-error-occurred-while-establishing-a-connection-to-sql-server/

Comment: It's not clear from this very general error message what's causing the error. You say it's an authentication error (did you set and use a password? For what account?). Also, the default configuration on installing SQL Server is that it is not available on the network. You need to use the management console on the local host to configure TCP access.

Comment: i got the above pop-up message when i connect to sql server managemen t studio.

Comment: Can you post some samples of your connection details? If you've got the host name wrong this will happen. Are you certain you're using the correct host name?

Comment: yes. i used the correct host name.

Comment: This is happend when i connect sql server. Server type:Database Engine and Authentication: Windows Authentication or Sql Server Authentication

Comment: and also why everytime if we start MS SQL Server in services then if we close the services window again we have start MS SQL Server manually,even If we set Start up mode to "AUTOMATIC"?

Comment: OK then... don't post your connection details...... Anyway that is not normal for SQL Server to not be running everytime you open services. That might explain the problem.